# How to fix "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class " error

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I tried to run webdriver script in my selenium java project then encountered this error.
I was running older version of eclipse before and everything was fine. This is started happening when i switched to eclipse 2019

I tried googling about the issue but not able to find a fix.

Software versions:

- Eclipse 2019-09 R
- JDK 8.0
- ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.105

```java
class NumberOne {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Selenium/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
}
}
```

And the error i'm facing

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess.<init>(OsProcess.java:54)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.<init>(CommandLine.java:38)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at numberOne.webdriver.main(webdriver.java:13)
```

Comment: Add the full class and the prarent to the question please. Strongly assuming you try to extend a final class which is prohibited in Java.

Comment: I didn't declare any final class

Comment: According to the stacktrace ` at numberOne.webdriver.main(webdriver.java:13)` ˛you didn't put the real class definition. In this case it's really hard to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
```

...implies that there was a version mismatch as there were inconsistencies between the classes you built against and the classes that you are testing against.

This seems to be a pure versioning issue and most likely the cause is that you have a conflict between your **build classpath** and your **launch classpath**. In other words, your program was compiled against a version of a class that wasn't `final` but your program was launched against a version of a class where it was `final`.

---

### Solution

The solution can be either/all of the following steps;

- If you are using *Maven*, delete the `~/.m2` cache/directory.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- (*WindowsOS only*) Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how that error implies a version mismatch.